# Can I rely on contiguous memory in this case?

Tags: c++

Consider a class:

```
template <typename T>
struct A{
  //...many public member functions...
  T x;
  T y;
  T z;
}
```

And another, similar:

```
template <typename T>
struct B{
  //many public member functions
  T x;
  T y;
}
```

While not specified here, `T` will always be either `float` or `int` or `bool`.

Now consider another struct:

```
struct Pair{
  A<float> a;
  B<float> b;
 }
```

Now a `vector`:

```
 std::vector<Pair> bigBunch;
```

How safe is it to assume that all the `x`, `y`, `z` in `bigBunch` will be contiguous?  I know that `vector` guarantees contiguous memory between its `Pair`s but I also know that `struct` does not necessarily guarantee contiguous memory since padding can happen. However, I thought padding is only a risk if your `struct` elements are different types.

I'd like to be able to get a pointer to `bigBunch[0].a.x` and then know that I can expect a contiguous stream of `float`s throughout the entire contents of `bigBunch`. And actually, a pointer to `bigBunch[0].a.x` would point to the same place as just saying `` `bigBunch[0].a ``.

Would it matter if `Pair.a` and `Pair.b` were the same or different type, such as mixing `int`s and `float` rather than both being the same type (`float` in this example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, nothing in the standard precludes the compiler from adding padding if it thinks it's a good idea. The compiler really has a lot of leeway in this matter. Which means the best thing to do is to be defensive and explicitly instruct your compiler to pack the data, even if eg, 4 byte float on 4 byte boundaries *shouldn't* cause padding.

My other recommendation is to use `static_assert` to verify everything is the size you want. Eg,

```
template <typename T>
struct A{
  //...many public member functions...
  T x;
  T y;
  T z;
} __attribute__ ((__packed__));
static_assert(sizeof(A) == 3*sizeof(T), "struct A shouldn't be padded");
```

If you don't have C++ 11, you can use [`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) instead. EDIT: the `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` bit after struct's closing brace is GCC-specific way of ensuring tightly packed struct.

Another thing you should consider is if you really get a benefit out of being able to treat your `vector<Pair>` as a big `float` array with no gaps. I understand that may make some algorithms more convenient to write if you have to iterate over everything, or if you have to pass the data to some other library that expects contiguous data. But I'm guessing you are doing a lot of math with these structs, and your compiler may be able to auto-vectorize some of it, eg by using SSE if `struct A` was 128-bit aligned. There is a lot of guesswork on my part in this part of my answer, so ignore it if it doesn't apply to you.

PS: don't forget the semicolon after the closing brace of your structs.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by this: *the best thing to do is to be defensive and explicitly instruct your compiler to pack the data* -- how would I do that?

Comment: @SebbyJohanns That question can't be answered without knowing what compiler you are using.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns It's compiler-specific. See my edit for GCC version.

Comment: is padding a compilation action, rather than a runtime action? i.e. you build the app and there is no padding when it runs on one machine, but there is padding when the same build runs on another?

Comment: (1) Padding is a compile time activity, but padding results may dependent on the architecture of the target machine. (2) In my experience, using non-standard gcc specific extensions to pack is not great -- it introduces more headaches than it solves. It is always better to write standard compliant code; that way the code is portable across compilers and architectures.

Comment: @ArunSaha "It is always better to write standard compliant code." I beg to differ. What's "better" depends on your requirements. If you have no portability requirements (which many projects legitimately don't), making your code portable can be a waste of time and energy. OP clearly needs a very specific memory layout which means he's tied to whatever architecture he's using, and he wants to take advantage of specifics of that architecture. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I'm working with an API that expects contiguous memory supplied to it (OpenGL drawing of vertices) and I'm using vectors and structs to organize my data. It would seem that writing code to guarantee contiguous storage in this context would require I give up the struct (if I'm not using compiler extensions) since at least I know with certainty that the vector alone is entirely contiguous.

Comment: perhaps a vector of vectors of vectors would be the main way to guarantee contiguous memory, as opposed to my current technique of a vector of structs that contain other structs/classes

Comment: @SebbyJohanns vector of vector (of vector...) is definitely ***NOT*** continuous.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns I would use the structs. In this case, I think most compilers won't bother padding your structs if all data members in the struct are the same type; you most likely don't need to ask the compiler to pack the data explicitly. Just use `static_assert` to verify that your compiler is doing what you want it to do, and you'll be fine. If the `static_assert` fails, then you will have to figure out how to deal with it; but if it doesn't, don't worry about it. PS: OpenGL was exactly my guess.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, while I know it's ugly organization, why wouldn't a vector of vectors not be contiguous in memory? The vector is supposed to guarantee contiguous memory layout for its enclosed items, and if those enclosures are also vectors, then I'd expect the full contents of the top-most vector to be in contiguous memory

Comment: @SchighSchagh: The portability requirements does not become apparent on day one. However, over the time of the project, many things happen, say for example (1) compiler upgrade to a newer version, (2) compiler change, (3) requirement to support the program in different processor (a) different architecture (x86 vs. PowerPC), (b) different endian-ness, so on and so forth. I have seen all these in my short experience in the software industry. Nobody knows what the future requirements would be. So, I consider it safe to be within the strict bounds of the standard. My humble opinion though.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: (continued) In this particular problem, I would ask why continuous memory layout is so important. And if it turns out to *really* absolute requirement, I would design my data structure differently, rather than depending on non-standard compiler specific extension. It may be only me. By the way, for `T = bool`, there would be padding when a `struct` has `3 T's`; and the `static_assert()` would fail in that case.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns `vector` allocates storage dynamically, so the only data stored in `vector` is actually metadata, eg a pointer to the real data and the size of the real data. If you have a vector of vectors, the meta-data of the inner vectors will be continuous, but each inner vector will have a pointer to an arbitrary memory location where it will store its real data

Comment: @ArunSaha (alpha) "I would ask why continuous memory layout is so important" Because he is passing the data to OpenGL, which is very strict about data layout. (beta) "By the way, for `T = bool`, there would be padding when a `struct` has `3 T's`". That's your opinion. My compiler (GCC 4.7) disagrees with you.

Comment: @ArunSaha (continued) Trying to future-proof things as you suggest is often more trouble than it's worth or otherwise counter-productive. Example: the Linux kernel. Linus stated in his original announcement that his toy OS is not and likely never will be portable. By chucking portability out the window initially, he was able to get it out in the open MUCH faster than Minix could be officially ported to 386, so Linux gained a substantial following before Minix for x86 was even released, and therefore Linux stuck and Minix became little more than a historical footnote.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: I don't know how you are testing the `bool` case, because `sizeof bool` is 1 byte, so three `bool` is expected to consume three bytes, but on 32-bit machines, generally, the objects are 4-byte aligned, hence I expected a one byte pad at the end. if it works for you, then never mind. Thanks for your comments and opinions, the Linux vs. Minix comparison is interesting, but that is much different level (commercialization, market capturing, time to market), I was talking only about writing programs that are compliant to the language standards. Thanks for the discussion, I enjoyed it

Comment: @ArunSaha I am testing the `bool` case as such: http://codepad.org/7ubClB7K As you say, they are "generally" 4-byte aligned. Not always.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: That is good, thanks for sharing. What do you think about this? http://codepad.org/iNv7r02F (some additions to your code)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27666/discussion-between-schighschagh-and-arun-saha)

Answer (score 1):

> However, I thought padding is only a risk if your struct elements are different types.

That isn't quite accurate, it is mainly related to how much space everything takes in memory.

Your example uses `float` which is 4 bytes and thus won't cause padding. The entire purpose of padding is to speed up memory access, 4 byte objects on 4 byte boundaries are fine.

So you should be able to assume you have a stream of `float`, but you probably wouldn't if `Pair` where on `bool`. The reason I say that is because it may decide that `b` would work best on a 4 byte boundary, which would introduce a byte of padding.

Answer (score 1):

> How safe is it to assume that all the x, y, z in bigBunch will be
>   contiguous?

Not safe. Compiler has freedom to pad. Depends on `T`

> a pointer to bigBunch[0].a.x would point to the same place as just
>   saying `bigBunch[0].a.

This is safe assumption.

> Would it matter if Pair.a and Pair.b were the same or different type,
>   such as mixing ints and float rather than both being the same type
>   (float in this example)?

It is not safe to assume. For `int` and `float`, we may be lucky, but may not be the case for `short` and `int`

The padding story changes between a 32-bit machine and a 64-bit machine. If you want your code to work on all architectures, you cannot make assumptions about padding and alignment.

For a general discussion, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

In summary, never assume anything about padding in your program :-)